# Kubuntu 20.10 can't log back in after logging out

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 20.10

Recently upgraded to 20.10. If I login from the sddm screen and then logout. I can login as another user, but if I use my username it does nothing after the splash screen - I get the spinning circle, the pointer appears and that's it apart from the odd flash of the HD LED.

Comment: Looks like the process kwin_x11 is still running for that user after they log out.

Comment: Seems like a kwin problem(?) Are you able to SSH into the machine remotely after this happens? If so, then try probing your graphics card. Maybe run something like `$nvidia-smi` if you are using an Nvidia GPU. If it takes a long time or does not finish, then you have a GPU error. Otherwise, this is probably a KDE bug and you should refer to the [KDE forum](https://forum.kde.org/)

Comment: If I kill kwin_x11 over SSH, then I am able to log back in. I've reported this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kwin/+bug/1905529.